# select statement combining multiple tables into one variable

Tags: sql, database, relational

An input form was designed for me that stores the information in 4 different tables in one database.  I now need to recombine these back into one.

The primary table is `Paintings`

All variable fields actual data is stored in `Medium_options`

The `PID` in `Paintings` and `MOID` in `Medium_options` are linked together in `Painting_medium`

My goal is to write a `SELECT` statement to combine this data into one $sql statement:

[Here](http://www.davidsdomaindesign.com/marknutt/test.php) is an example of what I have and need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this PHP?  I think you're looking for a `JOIN` statement to produce a combined result set -- not exactly mashing all fields into a single variable. That would more accurately be called string concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, changing the * to the columns you require (p.size, m.medium_name etc):

```
SELECT  *  
FROM    paintings AS p  
        INNER JOIN painting_medium AS pm  
            ON p.pid = pm.pid  
        INNER JOIN medium_options mo  
            ON pm.moid = mo.moid
        INNER JOIN medium m
            ON mo.medium_id = m.medium_id
```

So your first line would be along the lines of:

```
SELECT  p.category AS Category
       ,mo.medium_option AS Size
       ,m.medium_name AS Material
FROM   paintings AS p  
etc
```

Comment: this displays the paintings table with just the codes and not the discriptions i need.  it only creates multiple records for each medium associated to each record in medium options.  could you please help me display the data associated with each code in paintings and create multiple fields not records when there are multiple entries for medium.  the whole thing should be associated to the painting name but obviously is connected with pid and moid.  thanks,   david

Comment: As you've only given me three tables, I can only join three tables. Material appears to be an ID which presumably links to a materials table. Follow the example to add more tables. I assume you will do something along the lines of INNER JOIN materials m ON p.material = m.materialid

Comment: sorry, you are right i missed it.  reload the link on my original question.  the test.php file has been modified.  thanks

Comment: Updated answer to include new table

Comment: SELECT  p.painting AS painting
       ,mo.medium_option AS medium,
        mo.medium_option AS size
FROM   paintings AS p
       INNER JOIN painting_medium AS pm
            ON p.pid = pm.pid  
        INNER JOIN medium_options mo  
            ON pm.moid = mo.moid
i used the above code but i don't need line 3.  the issue is that i cannot put multiple line 1's or new 2's.  i have multiple fields in p.paintings and mo.medium_options, i get an error every time I add more of these options for each table.  in the answer above how would i add multiple fields in a single table?